# How does DBMS ensure durability without flushing

Tags: relational-theory, dbms

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onYjxRcToto&t=2445s&ab_channel=Devoxx) video, and at a certain point (don't recall the exact minute) the speaker says that the DBMS doesn't immediately flush the file when updates happen. He explains that IO operations are too slow to be performed every time you make a change.

So the question is **Practically, how do they can ensure durability?**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181180/why-do-sql-databases-use-a-write-ahead-log-over-a-command-log

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html